# How to submit a form and load a page with a new query string created by the form?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to provide a form that can create a post and load the editing page for the new created post immediately after the form submission. To load the editing page, I need correct `post_id`.

When the form is submitted, the post is created by the form handler in the script of editing page:

```
if(isset($_POST['create']){
  $post_id = create_new_post($args);
}else{
  $post_id = isset($_Request['post_id'])? $_Request['post_id'] :null;
}
if($post_id)
 load_editor($post_id);
```

The above code can load the editor upon form submission. But the editor page URL for the newly created post(`editor.php?action=edit)` is different from the editor page of existing posts(`editor.php?post_id=123&action=edit`).
How can I get the post_id and add it to the query string?

Comment: *"the post is created by the form handler"* - show the code of that form handler, it should reveal how you can get the post_id.

Comment: just updated my question